# Compare dictionaries and show only the differences in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have two dictionaries and would like to compare them and list the differences:
I thought about doing it as they are dictionaries which is not that easy after checking other answers here. One other way is to turn them to dataframe with pandas? I would like to take into consideration the same columns that are not in the same order too. So the check should be done by name.

For example 'KAEK' is listed way lower in the second dictionary if they were the same in name data type and length they should not considered different just because the order is different in the two dictionaries. How should I do it?

```
pst.schema

{'properties': OrderedDict([('KAEK', 'str:12'),
              ('PROP_TYPE', 'str:4'),
              ('ORI_TYPE', 'int:1'),
              ('ORI_CODE', 'str:100'),
              ('DEC_ID', 'str:254'),
              ('ADDRESS', 'str:254'),
              ('NUM', 'str:9'),
              ('LEN', 'float:19.11'),
              ('AREA', 'float:19.11')]),
 'geometry': 'Polygon'}


pst2.schema

{'properties': OrderedDict([('OBJECTID_1', 'int:9'),
              ('OBJECTID', 'int:9'),
              ('FID_PERIVL', 'int:9'),
              ('DESC_', 'str:254'),
              ('PROP_TYPE', 'str:4'),
              ('Shape_Leng', 'float:19.11'),
              ('Shape_Le_1', 'float:19.11'),
              ('Shape_Area', 'float:19.11'),
              ('PARCEL_COD', 'str:254'),
              ('KAEK', 'str:50'),
              ('NUM', 'int:4'),
              ('DEC_ID', 'int:4'),
              ('ADDRESS', 'int:4'),
              ('ORI_CODE', 'int:4'),
              ('ORI_TYPE', 'int:4')]),
 'geometry': 'Polygon'}
```

I was thinking about placing them in order like :

```
df = pd.DataFrame(pst2, columns=['NUM', 'DEC_ID','OBJECTID_1'])#place all the columns
#which doesn't work
```

But if it did, any gaps with different columns between the two dictionaries would create chaos.
For example, if columns in first would be:

```
A,B,C
```

and the second:

```
A,B,B2,C
```

would not be compared correctly. Therefore the comparison should occur by name.

To sum up: Compare these and show if any combination is different than the other. Either extra columns that don't exist in the other or something like this:

```
'ADDRESS', 'str:254'         #from 1st dictionary
'ADDRESS', 'int:4'           #from 2nd dictionary
```

Trying to show from which dictionary belong:

```
 pprint(set(('d1', el) if el in d1.items() else ('d2', el) for el in d2))


{('d2', 'ADDRESS'),
 ('d2', 'DEC_ID'),
 ('d2', 'DESC_'),
 ('d2', 'FID_PERIVL'),
 ('d2', 'KAEK'),
 ('d2', 'NUM'),
 ('d2', 'OBJECTID'),
 ('d2', 'OBJECTID_1'),
 ('d2', 'ORI_CODE'),
 ('d2', 'ORI_TYPE'),
 ('d2', 'PARCEL_COD'),
 ('d2', 'PROP_TYPE'),
 ('d2', 'Shape_Area'),
 ('d2', 'Shape_Le_1'),
 ('d2', 'Shape_Leng')}
```

the correct would be to show both dictionaries' differences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to find the symmetric differences between two of the OrderedDicts,

```
from collections import OrderedDict

>>> d1 = {'properties': OrderedDict([('KAEK', 'str:12'),
...               ('PROP_TYPE', 'str:4'),
...               ('ORI_TYPE', 'int:1')...

>>> d1 = d1['properties']

>>> d2 = {'properties': OrderedDict([('OBJECTID_1', 'int:9'),
...               ('OBJECTID', 'int:9'),
...               ('FID_PERIVL', 'int:9')...

>>> d2 = d2['properties']
```

---

```
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint(d1)
OrderedDict([('KAEK', 'str:12'),
             ('PROP_TYPE', 'str:4'),
             ('ORI_TYPE', 'int:1')...

>>> pprint(d2)
OrderedDict([('OBJECTID_1', 'int:9'),
             ('OBJECTID', 'int:9'),
             ('FID_PERIVL', 'int:9')...
```

---

```
pprint(set.symmetric_difference(set(d1.items()), set(d2.items())))
{('ADDRESS', 'int:4'),
 ('ADDRESS', 'str:254'),
 ('AREA', 'float:19.11'),
 ('DEC_ID', 'int:4'),
 ('DEC_ID', 'str:254'),
 ('DESC_', 'str:254'),
 ('FID_PERIVL', 'int:9'),
 ('KAEK', 'str:12'),
 ('KAEK', 'str:50'),
 ('LEN', 'float:19.11'),
 ('NUM', 'int:4'),
 ('NUM', 'str:9'),
 ('OBJECTID', 'int:9'),
 ('OBJECTID_1', 'int:9'),
 ('ORI_CODE', 'int:4'),
 ('ORI_CODE', 'str:100'),
 ('ORI_TYPE', 'int:1'),
 ('ORI_TYPE', 'int:4'),
 ('PARCEL_COD', 'str:254'),
 ('Shape_Area', 'float:19.11'),
 ('Shape_Le_1', 'float:19.11'),
 ('Shape_Leng', 'float:19.11')}
```

Then just use the result in whichever way you want ?

Further edit OP requested,

```
>>> d3 = set.symmetric_difference(set(d1.items()), set(d2.items()))
>>> pprint(set(('d1', el) if el in d1.items() else ('d2', el) for el in d3))
{('d1', ('ADDRESS', 'str:254')),
 ('d1', ('AREA', 'float:19.11')),
 ('d1', ('DEC_ID', 'str:254')),
 ('d1', ('KAEK', 'str:12')),
 ('d1', ('LEN', 'float:19.11')),
 ('d1', ('NUM', 'str:9')),
 ('d1', ('ORI_CODE', 'str:100')),
 ('d1', ('ORI_TYPE', 'int:1')),
 ('d2', ('ADDRESS', 'int:4')),
 ('d2', ('DEC_ID', 'int:4')),
 ('d2', ('DESC_', 'str:254')),
 ('d2', ('FID_PERIVL', 'int:9')),
 ('d2', ('KAEK', 'str:50')),
 ('d2', ('NUM', 'int:4')),
 ('d2', ('OBJECTID', 'int:9')),
 ('d2', ('OBJECTID_1', 'int:9')),
 ('d2', ('ORI_CODE', 'int:4')),
 ('d2', ('ORI_TYPE', 'int:4')),
 ('d2', ('PARCEL_COD', 'str:254')),
 ('d2', ('Shape_Area', 'float:19.11')),
 ('d2', ('Shape_Le_1', 'float:19.11')),
 ('d2', ('Shape_Leng', 'float:19.11'))}
```

Comment: it says:`unhashable type: 'collections.OrderedDict'`

Comment: The result is totally correct but I can't make it work.

Comment: Problem seems in `print (set(a.items()))`

Comment: Can you make it inform from which dictionary each line is, beside it maybe?So the reader can know which one has which?

Comment: Yes but it says `d3 is not defined` to me. And also It would be better if the order is like your previous result (not all d1 and then all d2).More readable.

Comment: Obviously you meant d2 , I still get only d2 values check the question I updated it with the result.What is going on?

Comment: @user122244 No I actually meant d3, which is the differences between two. Go ahead and try with the updated code, inform me.